# change radmenu click events

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Hi have a rad menu that is set in the master page and has all the url/links added there.

I am trying to change two of the radMenuitems navigation links from my aspx page code behind
D) replace the link with a javascript click event.
E) when you click then fire a vb.net void click event

thanks

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim rmenu As RadMenu = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("mymenu"), RadMenu)
    Dim D As RadMenuItem = DirectCast(rmenu.FindControl("dogs"), RadMenuItem)
    Dim E As RadMenuItem = DirectCast(rmenu.FindControl("cats"), RadMenuItem)


    D.NavigateUrl = nothing
    E.NavigateUrl = nothing


    D.click = "alert('you clicked on dogs')"
    E.click = Button1_Click

End Sub


Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'do this for cats only
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you not able to change the links? Try moving the code to Prerender event.

Comment: thanks but this did not work